# Telebot Python - Reply keyboard is not updated

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telebot

My Reply keyboard is not updated. Telebot Python

I need to update Reply keyboard but it only works with Inline keyboard. help please

```
markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
a = types.KeyboardButton("cat")
markup.add(a)
bot.edit_message_reply_markup(message.chat.id, message.message_id, reply_markup=markup)
```

It only gives the error "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message can't be edited".

Comment: I guess that you're trying to edit the incoming message, i.e. the message that you user sent. that's not going to work.